# Getting an error as "Expression expected"?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

HiEveryone,

I'm a beginner in `Javafx` and learning it to make app from someone tutorials, Now the problem is .. it's giving me an error as `Expression expected`? What's that mean ? Can anyone pls resolve my issue?..

Have a look into this [SCREENSHOT](http://postimg.org/image/4oi98yo5f/).

here is my source codes:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage primaryStage;
    BorderPane rootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        this.primaryStage=primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("Address App");

        initSample2Layout();
        showSample();
    }

    public void initSample2Layout(){
        try{

            //here loading files from FXML..
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("sample/Sample2.fxml"));
            rootLayout=(BorderPane).loader.load();
            Scene scene=new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void showSample(){
        try{

            //here we're loading files from FXML..
            FXMLLoader loader2=new FXMLLoader();
            loader2.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("sample/sample.fxml"));
            AnchorPane ap=(AnchorPane).loader.load();
            rootLayout.setCenter(ap);

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage(){
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid syntax :

`rootLayout=(BorderPane).loader.load();`

If you want to cast to `BorderPane`, do :

`rootLayout=(BorderPane)loader.load();`

And the same goes for `AnchorPane ap=(AnchorPane).loader.load();`, which should be changes to `AnchorPane ap=(AnchorPane)loader2.load();`.

Comment: ((BorderPane)loader).load(); in case precast ref cant access load

Comment: Now getting this one issue.. [ScreenShot](http://postimg.org/image/x6wb3itft/). ??

Comment: @nitinsharma That's because you called the variable `loader2` not `loader`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `rootLayout=(BorderPane).loader.load();` with an extra <kbd>.</kbd> character before `loader`.

You probably want the following:

```
rootLayout=(BorderPane) loader.load();
```